# How to delete Apple ID without password?

Tags: ipad, apple-id

How can I delete an Apple ID from an iPad without the password to the Apple ID?

I am purchasing a second-hand iPad from my friend's shop. The previous user of this iPad didn't reset all the content and I do not have his Apple ID password and his email.

Is there a way to delete previous owner AppleID account?

Answer (score 2):

you sure have his email if you know his Apple ID.
[You can delete it](http://support.apple.com/en-is/HT201274) if Find My iPad is not enabled. Otherwise it will become locked if it is.

[These what you do before buying](http://support.apple.com/en-is/HT201365) second hand Apple device